# Toshiba C655-S5512

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I was trying to log into a game and it came up with a driver error. When I looked in Device Manager it has a yellow question mark next to Ethernet Controller. I am not sure how it is missing. When I try to do driver updates it won't work. Not sure how I am supposed to fix this. I am able to get on the internet through my wireless router but not able to log onto the game. Can anyone give me any advice on how or if I am able to fix this issue.

If makes a difference my laptop runs on Windows 7

Answer (score 3):

Got to [Toshiba Support](http://support.toshiba.com/) and put in the serial number for your laptop, which should be on the underside of the laptop. Or you could put in the model number. After hitting enter to submit the information, click on the "Downloads and Updates" tab then select "LAN" Download and install the latest version of the Atheros LAN Driver for the Ethernet adapter in the laptop. I've also included a direct link to it below:

[Atheros LAN Driver version 2.1.0.6](http://cdgenp01.csd.toshiba.com/content/support/downloads/TC50131900E.exe)